# Div não fica com o 100% de altura

Tags: html, css

Estou fazendo a divisão de conteúdo, e coloco para a minha caixa1 ter 100% de altura e ela não fica, queria saber o porque ?, só fica quando eu coloco em px

Meu html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Pagina inicial</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="conteudo">
    <div class="caixa1">

    </div>
    <div class="caixa2">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
      cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
      proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Meu css

```
*{margin:0; padding: 0;}
body{font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 15px;}
.conteudo{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
.caixa2{
    width: 80%;
    background-color: red;
}
.caixa1{
    width: 20%;
    /*height: 620px;*/
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #E9F1F2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sim, é o esperado mesmo, pois a **porcentagem** age sobre um valor fixo digamos assim, então você está fazendo `width: 100%` de nada na verdade. Uma das formas que você pode utilizar porcentagem nas divs filhas é colocando um valor fixo para a div pai:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.conteudo {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: 500px;
}

.caixa2 {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}

.caixa1 {
  width: 50%;
  /*height: 620px;*/
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="conteudo">
  <div class="caixa1">

  </div>
  <div class="caixa2">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Width ou height que ele quer?

Comment: height que eu queria

Answer (score 1):

Uma abordagem seria colocar na classe `.conteudo` uma altura de `100vh`. A medida `vh` também é relativa e se baseia no *viewport*. Cada `vh` representa 1% do *viewport*. Teste com o seguinte css:

```
*{margin:0; padding: 0;}
body{font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 15px;}
.conteudo{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: flex-start;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100vh;
}
.caixa2{
    width: 80%;
    background-color: red;
}
.caixa1{
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #E9F1F2;
}
```